# Running H2O's Auto ML in a Loop

Tags: r, loops, machine-learning, data-science, h2o

I'm trying to run H2O's AutoML in a for loop but I'm having trouble saving the results after each iteration.

My plan is to run AutoML for each group in my data set, and saving the leaderboard for each of the groups. I already created subsetted datasets by group, so essentially what I want to do is loop through a list of h2o frames and build out automl for each of the datasets.  Below is the code I'm using:

```
#list of h2o frames 
dfs = c(df.UPR00015, df.UPR00019, df.UPR00020)
#list of frame id's
df_id = c("df.UPR00015", "df.UPR00019", "df.UPR00020")
#counter
count = 1
```

I then loop through the dataframes, and try to save each autoML object as follows:

```
for (df in dfs){

#run auto for each data frames and name it as id
assign(sprintf("aml_%s", df_id[count]) , h2o.automl(x = x,
         y = y,
         training_frame = df,
         max_models = 5))

 #increase iterator
 count = count + 1

}
```

This almost works. It returns 3 correctly named H2oAutoML objects (aml_df.UPR00015, aml_df.UPR00019, aml_df.UPR00020), but they all contain the same information in the leaderboard. This means that the same leaderboard gets created for the 3 different subsets. In my real application I have 40 different groups to build models for, but only listed 3 for simplicity's sake.

Can anyone please help me figure out where I'm going wrong, or perhaps share with me a better way to run AutoML for each data frame, or for each group in a dataset, in a loop? After I have a list of H2OAutoML bjects, I can easily loop through to retrieve the best models and all the metrics that comes along with that.

Thanks in advance,
Jurgen

Answer (score 2):

If you run H2O AutoML subsequent times on the same training set, by default, it will add more models to the leaderboard (because the auto-generated `project_name` will be identical).

The way to get separate leaderboards is to pass a unique value to the `project_name` argument for each execution of `h2o.automl()`.  An easy thing to use for a `project_name` is `Sys.time()` wrapped in an `as.character()` since it should be unique each time you run it.  If you have unique names for your datasets, you could use that instead.  Example below.

```
for (df in dfs){

#run auto for each data frames and name it as id
assign(sprintf("aml_%s", df_id[count]) , h2o.automl(x = x,
         y = y,
         training_frame = df,
         max_models = 5,
         project_name = as.character(Sys.time())))

 #increase iterator
 count = count + 1

}
```